# Neo4j nested XML file load

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to load nested xml in Neo4j DB but unable to figure out how to fetch nested elements from xml files.  In below xml file i would like extract both contact information.  How can i use parse to those element using apoc.load.xml ?

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genres>Fantasy</genres>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <contact>
      <email>123@gmail.com</email>
      <telephone>999999999999</telephone>
      </contact>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Comment: What are the current results you get with apoc.load.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of approaches with dealing with this:

[Here's a worked example](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/import/xml/#load-xml-examples-local-file) on the same book xml data you've got there in the APOC documentation.

The other approach is to use XPath. If I want to get at the items within the  section, I would do something like:

```
CALL apoc.load.xml('file.xml', '/catalog/book') yield value
RETURN value
```